# Why Won't My CSS Pull Down Menu Show in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu, pull

I thought I remembered testing my menu in IE, but now it doesn't work. :(
It works perfectly in Chrome and FireFox.
I tried looking at the other answers, but couldn't find an answer that fit mine.

You can check [**My Website here**](http://www.compray.com)

Thank you in advance! I'm new to CSS and this was definitely a struggle for me. I thought I conquered this already and now I'm just trying not to cry. :(

Comment: IE doesn't like invalid documents. Just by briefly looking, I can see you have `<font>` right inside your `<ul>`...

Comment: It's nice to see the font tag getting some use... bloatwha?

Answer (score 2):

You have `<font>` tag in twice in between your `<ul>` and `<li>` elements.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.compray.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Remove them and it will render properly.

Edit:

If you want different font sizes have you tried:

```
 <ul id="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Service</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>


#mainmenu li { //font styles }
#mainmenu ul li { //font styles }
```

Also, this is why it is not working, you are missing the dtd:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: I had added them because I wanted the main tab to be one size and the sub menu slightly smaller. It was the only way I could get it to work. I removed the font tags throughout the whole thing and the pull down still didn't work. It made my font smaller and put the services tab under products.  I am using SiteSpinner Pro. I will keep working on it. Thank you though!

Comment: font tags are yesterday's news, all css these days

Answer (score 0):

Your document is not valid. First thing you need to do is correct the markup. If you look [here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.compray.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you will see 18 errors in your markup.

The main problem is the `<font>` tag that is inside the `<ul>`. You can only place `<li>` tags inside of `<ul>` and then place whatever elements you need inside `<li>`.

`<font>` tag is deprecated and you should use [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to style your elements.

Comment: Thank you Lazar. I am using the Sitespinner Pro program. I do have this in the header- isn't this CSS? It wasn't looking right and that is why I put the font tags in there. I don't want all the text to be like that, just the menu bar.  I admit that I am a bit lost! :(

Comment: <style>
/*---- CROSS BROWSER DROPDOWN MENU ----*/
ul#nav {margin: 0 0 0 200px;}
ul.drop a { display:block; color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0px solid #021159; background: #000066; color: #fff;}
ul.drop { position: relative; z-index: 597; float: left;}
ul.drop li { float: left; line-height: 1.3em; vertical-align:text-bottom; zoom: 1; padding: 5px 10px; }
ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover { position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background: #1e7c9a; }

Comment: ul.drop ul { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 195px; background: #555; border: 1px solid #000066; }
ul.drop ul li { float: none; }
ul.drop ul ul { top: -2px; left: 100%; }
ul.drop li:hover > ul { visibility: visible }

-->
</style>

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me post it all at once. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I saw this message a little late, Jules has already updated her answer with the changes you need to make. I would strongly advise you to stop using such software for generating HTML/CSS and to start learning how to write the code yourself. That way it will be easier for you to understand the mistakes and for someone to help you out on StackOverflow.